# Название для философского факультета

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, сокращения

Известно, что филологический факультет зачастую называют *филфаком*, беря первые три звука (буквы) из первого и второго слова.

Существуют аналогично устроенные наименования типа *матфак*, *химфак*, но есть ли что-нибудь такое для философского факультета?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В отличие от филфака, философский — это филсфак или филос (http://lurkmore.to/%D0%A3%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9).

Answer (score 1):

Общепринятых правил тут нет *(При всем уважении к М_Г ссылка на полузабаненный в РФ Лурк источником таковых быть не может)* и вряд ли возможны, подобные сокращения не кодифицируются.
Конечно, чаще филологи считают филфаком именно свой факультет, но философы с ними не согласны. Последних меньше - и они дальше от сферы словотворчества, посему установилось некое соглашение: вне узкопрофессиональной группы философов филфаком считать именно филологический.
Но мне самому доводилось слышать, когда филфаком называли именно философский факультет - да еще обижались за попытку уточнить.

И вот пример подобной несогласованности. 
http://www.mk.ru/social/2015/06/03/filfak-mgu-fakultet-nevest.html

По склерозу, держал я в руках когда-то какой-то сборник задач для поступающих. Философский факультет там был точно назван "**философ. факом**" - именно, чтобы отличить его от "филфака"филологического. Но вот что это было... Не по математике же?! А других задачников я в те годы не пользовал...